# Cannot connect to Oracle database from Python via oracledb: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Tags: python, oracle, python-oracledb

I am trying to use [Oracle's python-oracledb library](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/python/quickstartpythononprem.html#linux-tab) to connect to an Oracle db that I've been able to connect to just fine manually in Oracle SQL Developer. I'm developing in VSCode using WSL Ubuntu on a VPN-connected VM owned by my company

Using a simple dict of info/credentials for a specific database, e.g.

```py
db_info = {
    'rdbms': 'Oracle',
    'dsn': oracledb.makedsn(oracle_am_db_host, oracle_am_db_port, sid=oracle_am_db_sid),
    'user': oracle_user,
    'pass': oracle_pass
}
```

I try to connect [as in Oracle's docs](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html) with username, password, and DSN (also having tried using DSN format `f'{db_name}:{db_port}/{db_sid}'` instead of `oracledb`'s `makedsn` function)

```py
conn = oracledb.connect(user=db_info['user'], password=db_info['pass'], dsn=db_info['dsn'])
```

but get the stack trace & error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user1/get-schemas-counts/get-schemas-counts.py", line 114, in <module>
    table_data = get_tables_counts(build_db_conn(db_info))
  File "/home/user1/get-schemas-counts/get-schemas-counts.py", line 51, in build_db_conn
    conn = oracledb.connect(user=db_info['user'], password=db_info['pass'], dsn=dsn_attempt)
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/oracledb/connection.py", line 1134, in connect
    return conn_class(dsn=dsn, pool=pool, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/oracledb/connection.py", line 523, in __init__
    impl.connect(params_impl)
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/connection.pyx", line 449, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl.connect
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/connection.pyx", line 445, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl.connect
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/connection.pyx", line 411, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl._connect_with_params
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/connection.pyx", line 392, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl._connect_with_description
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thin/connection.pyx", line 358, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl._connect_with_address
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/oracledb/errors.py", line 162, in _raise_err
    raise exc_type(_Error(message)) from cause
oracledb.exceptions.OperationalError: DPY-6005: cannot connect to database (CONNECTION_ID=sR7jFJ3PnW2DK76pG1OGAw==).
[Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Thinking this might be a DNS issue from some threads I've read, I tried adding some more expansive nameservers to my `/etc/resolv.conf` file but to no avail. Also tried restarting my terminal sessions

Comment: What connection string do you use with SQL Developer?   Review the python-oracledb doc [JDBC and Oracle SQL Developer Connection Strings](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#jdbc-and-oracle-sql-developer-connection-strings).  Also note that `makedsn()` was obsoleted by https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/connect_param.html#connparam